# Can a configuration file be used to describe a JAXB export?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a rather large object tree which I want to export to XML. An object named Person is used at several places (as userCreated, userModified of many child entities, as client, etc)

I would like to export an instance of the object tree as XML and JAXB seems the way to do it.

But, I want to avoid annotating dozens of properties with @XmlTransient. On the contrary, I would like to have a central configuration file in which I could specify the children and properties to export.

Is that possible with JAXB?

Or is it not the right tool for the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If less than half of the properties are mapped then you can specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` on the class and then only fields/properties will JAXB Annotations will be mapped to XML.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html

If you want to configure the mappings by XML the [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) implementation (I lead this project) offers a mapping file extension you can use.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html

Comment: @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) looks like a good start, thanks. MOXy with a mapping-file looks like the perfect solution, I'm now looking into using it with Hibernate.